# A dropdown field make the conatiner "scrollable"

Tags: html, css, reactjs

A dropdown field make the conatiner "scrollable" and cuts off  the dropdown selections, selector must float above the container.

for other reasons I cannot change the overflow: auto in the outer container

Thanks for helping me

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import styled from "styled-components";


export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const difference = useRef();

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const height = ref.current.offsetHeight;
    difference.current = height;
    console.log(height);
  }, [expanded]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: "60px", backgroundColor: "lightblue", overflow: "auto" }}
    >
      <div ref={ref} style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <span onClick={() => setExpanded((previousState) => !previousState)}>
          See Options
        </span>
        {expanded && (
          <div>
            <div>
              {["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"].map((option, i) => (
                <div
                  style={{
                    border: "1px solid green",
                    width: "60px"
                  }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    console.log(option);
                  }}
                >
                  {option}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your dropdown container have an absolute position, relative to the container it's in.

Absolute position means your parent container will ignore the width and height of the dropdown, which means the dropdown will not affect the height of the parent container.

Comment: I do not know where it will be exactly, since the container is a table that can have multiple columns

Comment: Try using `position:absolute` without specifiying any position. I believe it would stay in place yet it would be taken out of the flow and wouldn't cause the container to scroll.